# Restrict multiple attributes in the same section in Visual Studio config

Tags: .net, visual-studio, rider, editorconfig

We are developing common set of coding style rules for our company, and noticed that some of junior devs are using attributes like

```
[Attr1, Attr2, ..., AttrN]
```

which is not good in our case because in some places we have a lot of them and it makes code somewhat unreadable.

So I tried to find a setting for this in .editorconfig, but it seems that it's not configurable this way. You can configure it in IDE settings though, both in Rider and VS. We created a mechanism to distribute style settings to local env of each dev via NuGet.

I'm wondering if there is a way to configure it in some file (not necessarily in .editorconfig) so that we can distribute them? The key point is that responsible person makes styling changes and then they are being automatically distributed to devs without any manual setup needed.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not possible using code-style settings. I'd recommend writing a little Roslyn analyzer for this ([see here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/roslyn-sdk/tutorials/how-to-write-csharp-analyzer-code-fix)).